# TypeScript string literal to basic type

Tags: typescript

I have some settings in a JSON file and if i return one setting value, i want it to be typed:

```
[
    {
        "name":"setting_1",
        "type":"number",
        "value":"12"
    },
    {
        "name":"setting_2",
        "type":"boolean",
        "value":"false"
    },
    {
        "name":"setting_2",
        "type":"string",
        "value":"setting string"
    }
]
```

Is it possible to have one function to get the value of the setting returned with the type of the type-attribute?

```
const settings = [
  { name: 'setting_1', type: 'number', value: '12' },
  { name: 'setting_2', type: 'boolean', value: 'false' },
  { name: 'setting_2', type: 'string', value: 'default string' },
];

function getSetting(name: string): <Type> {
  const { value, type } = settings.find((s) => s.name === name);

  return <type>value;
}

const setting: boolean = getSetting('setting_2');
```

So that i get errors like this:

```
const setting: number = getItems('setting_2'); >> TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: All your values are strings. Regardless of how you manipulate the type system, TypeScript will not automatically convert your strings to numbers and booleans.

Comment: const setting: any = getSetting('setting_2'); Since value can be a boolean string and number